# Firefox Addon SDK Hotkeys and context menu options don't work on Authentication Required Popup

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an addon to securely store / retrieve information including user profiles and passwords (an interface to a password manager). It uses a button (or a hotkey) to take information from entry fields and store it.

However this does not work on those sites which choose to popup an “Authentication Required” panel.

If I add a context menu option to do the same thing this also does not work on that panel.

Can anyone think of a way of triggering a function from that panel?

Comment: After a bit more blundering around I notice that XUL addons can listen for a DOMWillOpenModalDialog event. However none of the SDK panel events seem to work and I am now trying to find a way of listening for this event from the sdk.

Comment: What you need to do is `addEventListener` to your popup for `keyup` and `keydown` or `keypress`. Or you could try inserting a keyset element into your panel, actually that might work see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27819679/add-shorcut-key-in-a-restartless-firefox-addon/27829703#27829703