# Can I listen for a XUL type event in the add-on SDK

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to listen for the event which occurs when an "Authorisation Required" dialogue is displayed (see [Firefox Addon SDK Hotkeys and contect menu options dont work on Authentication Required Popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27807474/firefox-addon-sdk-hotkeys-and-contect-menu-options-dont-work-on-authentication-r)).

However I notice that XUL addons can listen for a DOMWillOpenModalDialog event which is apparently triggered when this dialogue box opens. None of the SDK panel events seem to be triggered.

Is there a way to listen for this event from within the addon SDK?

------Edit------

Going on from Noitidart 's sugestion I then tried a couple of other events and they fire. Both the attempts below work.

```
var events = require("sdk/system/events");
function listener(event) {console.log("An event popup was activated.");}
events.on("xul-window-visible", listener);

CWin.addEventListener("DOMWillOpenModalDialog", function() {CWin.setTimeout(NfyBox, 500);}, true);
function NfyBox() {
console.log("An event popup was activated.");
worker = tabs.activeTab.attach({
    contentScriptFile: self.data.url("notifybox.js")
});
worker.port.emit("notify");
}
```

However that is as far as I get, in the contentScriptFile, a console.log of document produces :-

```
console.log: infstr: {"location":{"assign":"function assign() {\n    [native cod
e]\n}","replace":"function replace() {\n    [native code]\n}","reload":"function  
reload() {\n    [native code]\n}","toString":"function toString() {\n    [nativ
e code]\n}","valueOf":"function valueOf() {\n    [native code]\n}","href":"http:
//c1s4-1e-syd.hosting-services.net.au:2082/unprotected/redirect.html","origin":"
http://c1s4-1e-syd.hosting-services.net.au:2082","protocol":"http:","username":"
","password":"","host":"c1s4-1e-syd.hosting-services.net.au:2082","hostname":"c1
s4-1e-syd.hosting-services.net.au","port":"2082","pathname":"/unprotected/redire
ct.html","search":"","hash":""}}
```

But an attempt to get getElementById or anything else I tried comes back undefined. I am obviously making some simple mistake, but can’t see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes listen to popup events. In this case `popupshowing`: [MDN : PopupEvents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/PopupGuide/PopupEvents)

This is an example that prevents the main menu at top right (tri stripe menu button) from closing by listening to `popuphiding` and preventing it:

```
var PUI = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').document.querySelector('#PanelUI-popup');
try {
PUI.removeEventListener('popuphiding', previt, false);
} catch (ignore) {}
    var previt = function(e) {
    PUI.style.opacity = 1;
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
    return false;
}
PUI.addEventListener('popuphiding', previt, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for that - unfortunately I can’t get that to work. I tried:-
<pre><code>
const {Cc,Ci,Cu} = require("chrome");
var {Services} = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var PUI = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').document.querySelector('#PanelUI-popup');
PUI.addEventListener('popupshowing', function() {console.log("A popup was activated.");} , false); 
</code></pre>
And it produced no output. However you did get me trying some other stuff, which gets a bit further (see edited question)

Comment: @BushAl change `var {Services} = Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');` to just `Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');`

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I am new to both Addons and js. I inserted the code in main.js, and understood why PUI was null (no page loaded) so tried as below but PUI is always null. Just to be clear the auth popup can be seen visiting lelal.com/cpanel 
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
tabs.on("ready", logURL);
function logURL(tab) {
 console.log(tab.url);
 var PUI =Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').document.querySelector('#Pa‌​nelUI-popup');
 PUI.addEventListener('popupshowing', function() {console.log("A Popup was activated.");} , false);
}

Comment: @BushAl `PUI` is actualy on the window, it doens't check the page (tab content) so as long as a main browser window is there then it will work. Is `Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser')` can be null though if you don't have any windows with the main menu though. So check `var recentWin = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser'); if (recentWin) { var PUI = recentWindow.getElementById('PanelUI'); } else { Services.prompt.alert(null, 'error', 'no browser window') }`

Comment: I have put the exact code in the comment below at the top of the main.js of my addon sdk. It reports "No PanelUI". So the browser
window exists but PUI is null (as before).

Comment: const {Cc,Ci,Cu} = require("chrome");
Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm');
var recentWin = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
if (recentWin) {
 var PUI = recentWin.document.getElementById('PanelUI');
 if (PUI) {
 PUI.addEventListener('popupshowing', function() {console.log("A Popup was activated.");} , false);
 } else {
  Services.prompt.alert(null, 'error', 'No PanelUI'); 
 }
} else {
 Services.prompt.alert(null, 'error', 'no browser window');
}

Comment: Thats very weird, can you do cfx make and upload your addon to github.

Comment: the addon sdk I am using doesnt seem to have a make, just an "cfx xpi" to create the addon, so I have uploaded this to https://github.com/abreingan/InfStr/ hope this helps - thanks again for your help